# Readable generated xml comments

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, api, comments

Is there some simple, standard way of converting my C# xml comments generated xml file into a format that is easily read.  I have no need for setting any formatting, adding new tags, etc, I just need to display my generated file eg. javadoc style or not similar, in the most simplest, easiest way possible.  Cheers.

Comment: To clarify, I have already an xml file generated from my comments, but its generally unreadable.  Can I easily run this file through a tool or similar that will convert it to say html or similar. Javadoc automatically styles generated files 'readably'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) and [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/), which produces MSDN style help files from xml doc comments.  You can find a detailed guide [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/taming-sandcastle-a-.net-programmers-guide-to-documenting-your-code/).

Another option is [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl), which I found to be easier to use than Sandcastle.  In the end, I preferred the look of the help file that Sandcastle produced, so I chose Sandcastle over Doxygen.

Comment: I've since played with Doxygen and find it very useful in both extracting documentation from code, and presenting the documentation.  Its powerful and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ghost Doc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have variety of tools for doing this:

1. [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Devscribe](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/devscribe)

You can get a list of many other document generators [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators)!